# Use sed and wget to retrieve links only

Tags: linux, bash, sed

What I need to do is retrieve a link through a command such as:

`wget --quiet -O - linkname`

Then pipe it to sed to just display ONLY the links on the page not the formatting.

What i got so far only displays lines with the all the html code along side of it.

Comment: could you show the code you written for last 2 lines? Also what is your expected output? show a sample

Comment: You might also want to look into [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what I was looking for.

```
sed -n "/href/ s/.*href=['\"]\([^'\"]*\)['\"].*/\1/gp"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pipe the result to `grep` with `-o`(match-only) option:

```
$ wget --quiet -O - http://stackoverflow.com | grep -o 'http://[^"]*'
```

To get all url inside `href="..."`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")'
```

Comment: I am looking more along the lines of using sed. I need to learn it. What I got is this... but I want an all sed command - wget --quiet -O - link | grep -o '<a href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' | sed -e 's/^<a href=["'"'"']//' -e 's/["'"'"']$//'

Comment: On MacOS and other BSD distributions: `ggrep -oP` instead of `grep -oP`. GNU `grep`. Installation required.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "<a href=" sourcepage.html
  |sed "s/<a href/\\n<a href/g" 
  |sed 's/\"/\"><\/a>\n/2'
  |grep href
  |sort |uniq
```

1. The first grep looks for lines containing urls. You can add more elements
   after if you want to look only on local pages, so no http, but
   relative path.
2. The first sed will add a newline in front of each *a href* url tag with the \n
3. The second sed will shorten each url after the 2nd " in the line by replacing it with the */a* tag with a newline
   Both seds will give you each url on a single line, but there is garbage, so
4. The 2nd grep href cleans the mess up
5. The sort and uniq will give you one instance of each existing url present in the sourcepage.html